# Phone gets heated when running my application

Tags: iphone, ios, device

When I use my application for awhile, I have noticed that the device gets hot. Apple devices usually get hot when running applications, so I want to know if there's a method to check if I have done something wrong in my application.

I don't think the Allocations tool in Instruments could help me diagnose the problem.

Comment: Profile for CPU usage: too much CPU use is what heats up the phone, and eats up the battery too.

Comment: Apple devices usually gets heated, but is there a method to measure this temperature and see if it has exceeded the maximum allowed temp by apple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instruments can definitely help you solve this. Your device gets hot as a direct result of intense CPU activity, which Instruments can track and show you your CPU usage and memory allocations.

Comment: Apple devices usually gets heated, so how do i know if my application is causing the heat ? and is there a method to check if the application has exceeded the maximum allowed temperature ?

Comment: Just because the device gets hot doesn't mean that you're exceeding any max temperature, it just means your consuming a lot of device resources, which isn't always a bad thing, but will often result in loss of battery life for your user. Don't worry about a temperature threshold, I don't believe theres anything you can do programmatically that can cause the device to reach this limit. The overheat safeguards are triggered from something like leaving your iPhone in a black car on the beach all day.

Comment: Side note, what model iPhone are you using?

Comment: Well if your app is consuming enough resources to heat an iPhone 4 enough that you think it's a problem, you may want to rethink some of your allocations.

Answer (score 0):

For IOS check GPU consumption in XCode dev tools, which might cause heating apps while using.

Suppose your app has **BackdropFilter Widget** which is one of the reasons for increasing GPU because IOS consumes more GPU to render BackdropFilter Widget.

This works for me.